# Pandas: iteratively concatenate columns stored in a dictionary of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, for-loop, dataframe

Suppose I have a dictionary of `pandas` dataframes where the keys are `0, 1, 2, ..., 999`, and the values are dataframes like this (`test_df`):

```
          A         B         C
0  1.438161 -0.210454 -1.983704
1 -0.283780 -0.371773  0.017580
2  0.552564 -0.610548  0.257276
3  1.931332  0.649179 -1.349062
4  1.656010 -1.373263  1.333079
5  0.944862 -0.657849  1.526811
```

Say that the index means nothing to you, and that you want to create a new dataframe where columns `A` and `B` are concatenated:

`mydf=pd.concat([test_df[0]['A'],test_df[0]['B']], axis=1, keys=['A','B'])`

Now, **can I use this line inside a for loop which iterates over all the keys in my dictionary of dataframes?**

If not, what would be another way of doing this? The result would be a dataframe with two columns, `A` and `B`, and `6x1000` rows. The index column would therefore go from `0` to `5999`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `df_dic` is your dictionary, you can do:

```
pd.concat([df[['A', 'B']] for df in df_dic.values()]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Here is what the result looks like if `df_dic` contains two key-value pairs:

[image]

Comment: Just to rest assured: I take I won't lose the A-to-B pairings, am I right?

Comment: When you do `df[['A', 'B']]`, it selects columns `A` and `B` from your data frames, so the list comprehension creates a list of data frames where `A` and `B` from each data frame are the same order as in the original data frames. So yes it shouldn't.